# Do I have to delete the default folder?

Tags: theming

Do I have to delete `default` folder which is located under `/sites`? Because I installed new theme and I think there is no need to keep the default theme.

And, if I can't delete it, please tell me why?

Comment: Unless you have a multisite setup your settings.php file will be in sites/default. Why do you want to delete it at all, is it just to remove (potential) clutter?

Comment: @Clive because I installed new theme and the style for the new theme located in the default file while the new theme has style file and not used, why ? btw I'm learning and new

Comment: FWIW, I don't actually understand the question. What's the connection between the default folder and the theme issue? What is the theme issue?

Comment: @Letharion my new theme take the style of default folder

Comment: @MohammedF.Ghazo I have no idea what that means.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you're running a multi-site or another non-standard configuration (and the way the question is phrased, I do not think you do), you can't delete the `sites/default` folder or the files within it.

The reason you can't delete it is because: This directory (unless you've set up a multi-site or similar) contains (among other things) the `settings.php` for your site. If you delete it, all you settings including the database credentials will be lost, and your site will stop working.

Please also note that the `sites/default` folder has *nothing* whatsoever to to with the theming of your site.

If you have installed a new theme, and have the problem that the new theme is not used, this problem is *not* related to the presence of the `sites/default` folder on your site.

Comment: default doesn't have to contain the settings.php file, so I actually think this answer is incorrect, at least the way it's currently phrased.

Comment: @Letharion, there is nothing in the question that suggests the OP is running a muliti-site, but to make extra sure, I've amended the answer to cover this eventuality.

Comment: I like the new phrasing much better. +1

Answer (score 1):

Drupal default themes should be on themes/* and you shouldn't touch those, either modify or delete any content of what's considered core is not recommended.

Anything that is under sites/ is considered part of your application so if you're sure you're not using the themes under sites/default, there's no problem with deleting them.

You need to be sure to leave your settings.php, files and other useful content intact as you're using those (either in default or in a multisite)